# How to extract pages without comments in acrobat pro 10

Tags: acrobat

I have been searching for this in many places.  Tried PDFSam but not working for me in this situation.  I would like to extract pages without comments or sticky notes or pencil mark in Acrobat as a separate pdf to check why these pages were not commented on.  I am not a coder, but I have a little Javascript knowledge and I have never written a JS code for Acrobat.  Kindly guide me in the right direction to write this javascript code.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

an easy way to get around this is, you can extract the pages you want.  And then delete all the comments.
This 2-step way helps solve your problem.
Note that you don't want to delete the comments one by one.
You click the comments button usually sitting on the lower left corner, which will show all the comments on the left pane.  Click any one of it, and hit Ctrl+A and then hit Delete key on your key board.  Save and you are done.
It saves you the pain you may get from writing a JS code.
Hope this helps!